# jQuery slider set integer to .01

Tags: increment

jQuery increment slider: how can I set the slider to increment by .01?  I set the step to "step: .01," but the slider does not increment by .01 it increment by .1

The slider needs to increase by $.01 cents so that our customers can keep track of every penny in their account.

Comment: You need to state what jQuery plugin you're using to create the slider. If it's jQuery UI, state that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I stumbled upon it trying to find a solution so I figured I would come back to this post and tell everyone what I did for any of those still looking for a way to fix it

Basically I took my original scale that went from 0-20 and made it go from 0-200 later in my code I simply divided by 10 for the out put and it works great now obviously this adds a few lines of code by making you have to reassign variable after you divide them by 10 but you can make the slider now increment by .1 and with simple math by making it 0-2000 and dividing by 10 then the slider would increment by .01 hope this helps someone

Comment: By far the best answer! I will have to use this for sure!

Answer (score 1):

i just tested it and does work
but you have to set the step:0.01, you can test your self this is the example  i was working on for yaxis and x-axis. i hope this helps and that its not too late

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){

 $( "#x" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: -6,
        max: +6,
        step:0.01,
        values: [0,2],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#amountx" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

     $( "#y" ).slider({
        range: true,
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: -12,
        max: 12,
        step:0.01,
        values: [1,2],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amounty" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
   $( "#amountx" ).val(  $( "#x" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - " + $( "#x" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
     $( "#amounty" ).val( $( "#y" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - " + $( "#y" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );});</script>
<style>#x{top:115px;width:230px;}#y{height:230px;}</style><div id='x'></div><div id='y'></div><input type='text' id='amountx'/><input type='text' id='amounty'/>
```

Comment: please give me your feedback if this was helpful or not

Answer (score 0):

You can't, otherwise the value wouldn't be an integer.

There have been efforts to allow decimal steps using the slider, [the one seeming to be successful](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-slider-does-not-support-step-attribute) (though I haven't examined in great detail) requires hacking the jQuery UI library itself to add decimal support.